# Is there a way to disable view data copy when copying a schema (objects and data) with SQLDeveloper?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been playing around with copying a schema using SQL Developer's Database Copy tool. I have a view that selects from a table in the same schema. When I do the copy SQL Developer generates inserts for both the table and the view. I can't figure out a way to tell it to only copy data for tables.

In the wizard there is a screen for selecting specific tables and views to copy. When I do not select any views it assumes all views.

The only idea I've come up with is to create a dummy view and select that as the only view to copy data for. Or to copy as a two phased approach of tables and data once and then views and other objects in a second pass without data.

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug and should be fixed in the latest version.